# PHP while loop based on MYSQL query results missing out first row

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have this php getting rows from my database, however when I while loop the results out into divs on my site, it always misses out the first row it has retrieved, and I have no idea why.

```
                $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'cdb')
                or die('Error connecting');

                if( isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
                  $_SESSION['page'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
                }else{
                  $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
                }
                $records_per_page = 8;

                $where =  substr($where, 0, -3);

                $query = "SELECT * FROM cars 
                              ".$where."";

                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
                  or die("Error in query: '$query'");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $i = 0;
                $start = ($_SESSION['page'] - 1) * $records_per_page;
                $end = ($_SESSION['page']) * $records_per_page;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and $i < $end) 
                {
                  $i++;
                  if( $i > $start ) 
                  {    
                    echo'                   

                    <div class="result_main flip'.$i.' shadow2">

                        <div class="main_result_carname">   
                            <h2><b>'.$row['make'].' '.$row['model'].'</b></h2>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="main_result_carprice">
                            <h2><b>£'.$row['price'].'</b></h2>
                        </div>


                    </div>';
                  }
                }
                ?>
```

Looking at it, I feel it should work fine, but always starts at the 2nd row, the only variable I can see which might affect this is $i. There no reason why it starting at 1 should be wrong, but anyway, making it -1 results in no records showing, and making it 0 makes it stay the same while making it -1 makes it start at the 3rd row, and making it 2 it starts at 2d row.

Comment: where does your `$where` cam from? (just out of interest)

Comment: $where = " WHERE ";

`foreach ($_POST['carID'] as $carID) 
{  
 $where = $where." carIndex = ".$carID." OR";
}`

There might be an easier way, but I post an array and need to apply the values in it to the where clause. The I have `$where = substr($where, 0, -3);` just before the query to get rid of the " OR" at the end.

Comment: missing sanitize aside... `$where = "carIndex IN (".implode(',', $_POST['carID']).")"` no need for substr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

that is before your

```
$i = 0;
```

---

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
  or die("Error in query: '$query'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$i = 0;
```

---

That is selecting your 1st row and moving the internal pointer forward so

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and $i < $end)
```

will begin selecting from the 2nd row

Comment: Awww Yisss Thank you, not sure why I put that in there, tis showing the first row now.